# How do I format a date in Javascript to look like Monday, June 16, 2020

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to find a way to implement a date that is easy to understand on my website. I want it to look like the following: Monday, June 16, 2020. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Also, read this if you're planning on working with `Date` objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date